# JAVA Use two keystore same application

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, jks

I'm trying to develop an application in java that basically gets a large number of data from REST-JSONs APIs and insert that on a DB. My problem is that two of the URLs I was working with, thrown errors about SSL certificates. To solve that, I created a jks file and inserted their certificates. The problem is, once I put that on my code, jvm only uses the certificates on that file, all others are rejected. So I want to make my application accepts jsons from either "cacerts.jks" and "custom.jks". Please don't tell me to add the certificates to the "teste.jks" (native from jvm), because the app won't run on my computer, I need the certificates on a sepparated file.

One more observation, I'm working with about 90 different URLs and I'm using  the following line to indicate jvm, which keystore to use:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/libs/teste.jks");
    //or (for native one):
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a subclass of javax.net.ssl.TrustManager or one of its subclasses like javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager (MyTrustManager in the example below) and tweak the SSLContext to use it. Your trust manager implementation can do whatever you want with regard to validating/trusting certificates.

```
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        MyTrustManager tm = new MyTrustManager();
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, sr);
        SSLContext.setDefault(context);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create *two* TrustManagers, one that uses the default truststore and one that uses your own, and initialize the SSLContext with both:

```
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm1, tm2}, null);
```

See the JSSE Reference Guide for further details.

Comment: Can you help me to create these TrustManagers? One is the default and the other from the jks file...